# Как подключится к двум разным ip одновременно?

Tags: linux, сеть, vpn, openvpn

У меня есть два файла .ovpn. Выглядят они подобным образом:

```
dev tun
proto tcp
remote 61.211.140.7 1949
;http-proxy-retry
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port]
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
client
verb 3
```

Различаются в этих файлах только ip и port. Я хочу делать запросы к разным ресурсам с разных ip. Но как я понимаю, то после первого подключения к серверу остается только его ip. Как подключится к двум разным ip одновременно? К одному серверу я подключался с помощью команды `openvpn --config /tmp/tmp73fds6`

Comment: `К одному серверу я подключался с помощью команды` — ну так подключайтесь после этого ко второму. есть проблемы? так изложите их, нажав [edit].

Comment: А что Вы хотите в результате получить?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Я исправил, возможно, станет понятнее что я хочу

Comment: нет, вы так и не изложили, что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: А что хочется получить (ну кроме того, что Вы будете подключены к двум vpn?)

Comment: что именно ты понимаешь под «Я хочу делать запросы к разным ресурсам с разных ip»?

Comment: что то мне подсказывает, что автор хочет сканить/скрапить/парсить разные ресурсы, которые банят за это и просто хочет использовать два vpn сервера, тем самым увеличив время скана в три раза.